# DiscordJS v14 : ReferenceError: Cannot access 'cmd' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do the clickable text command in the new version of discordjs but this error always comes up..

```
`</${_cmds.name}:${_cmds.id}>\n╰ ${_cmds.description}`}).join("\n")
     ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access '_cmds' before initialization
```

Here is my code for this

```js
_cmd = client.slashCommands.filter((x) => x.category && x.category === "Info").map((x) => {
  let _cmds = client.application.commands.cache.find((x) => x.name)
  `</${_cmds.name}:${_cmds.id}>\n╰ ${_cmds.description}`}).join("\n")
  await msg.edit({ embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setColor(ee.color).setDescription(`**Info Commands!**\n*some of the commands are not be visible yet to public.*\n\n${_cmd}`)] })
```

I want to get the command name along with the command ID to create the clickable text command. First, I did it to get the command category so that it will only fetch the command that was in the category then I used `application.commands.cache` to list down all the commands in the category and use `.find()` to find the name to get the command ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is caused by the (lack of) automatic semicolon insertion.

You're using a template literal `` `</${_cmds.name}:${_cmds.id}>\n╰ ${_cmds.description}` `` and these can be tagged with a function (like `` functionName`${a} and ${b}` ``. So the interpreter reads this as a single line:

```js
let _cmds = client.application.commands.cache.find((x) => x.name)`</${_cmds.name}:${_cmds.id}>\n╰ ${_cmds.description}`}).join("\n");
```

Now you can see that you declare the variable `_cmds` and you also want to access it before it was initialised in the scope (ie trying to use `_cmds.name`)

To solve this, you could add a semicolon before the first backtick (`` ` ``) but even then there is no return statement inside your `map()` so it will return `undefined`. So return the template literal, like this:

```js
_cmd = client.slashCommands
  .filter((x) => x.category && x.category === 'Info')
  .map((x) => {
    let _cmds = client.application.commands.cache.find((x) => x.name);
    return `</${_cmds.name}:${_cmds.id}>\n╰ ${_cmds.description}`;
  })
  .join('\n');
await msg.edit({
  embeds: [
    new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(ee.color)
      .setDescription(
        `**Info Commands!**\n*some of the commands are not be visible yet to public.*\n\n${_cmd}`,
      ),
  ],
});
```

Comment: thank you for the solution and answering my problem, but there a new problem. After i followed your guide the command only showed up is only one... but that command isn't even inside the category.

Comment: That's weird. The problem is I don't know what your `client.slashCommands` is or if there is anything else that could cause this issue. If you want you could upload more of your code to a site like pastebin.com and send the link here so I can take a look at it.